# How to call an iOS scheme

Tags: ios, delphi, idhttp

Trying to call an iOS scheme for iOS printing with Star printers and Delphi, and I am not sure how to call it or what component should I use, I am using iDHTTP to make the call. Star Printing Documentation:  (http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx) http://www.starmicronics.com/support/ZipFile.aspx?sat2=242&id=242&type=4&referrer=http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx&tabText,  Here is the code:

```
function PostExample: string;
var
 server: TIdHttp;
 Parameters,response: TStringStream;
 begin
   server := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   response := TStringStream.Create;
   Parameters := TStringStream.Create('=<PrintingData>&size=3&drawer=ahead&back= <Callback URL scheme>', TEncoding.UTF8); 
   server.Post('starpassprnt://v1/print/nopreview?html',Parameters,response);
end;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't call scheme on iOS this way, you open the URL. There is no background calling of other apps, you acutely open the other app bij calling the app URL scheme. It's not an HTTP service you can consume.

Comment: Thank you, so should I use TApplicationEvent.OpenURL(' ?

Comment: Yes, this will open the app associated with the given scheme and pass the parameter to this app.